# Applying a macro to a form without defining the macro

Tags: clojure, lisp

Is there a way to expand a macro without actually defining it? My situation is that I have a bunch of macros that may/may not override clojure macros, I need to a apply those macros to a list of s-expressions?

Answer (score 4):

Macroexpand can't see macros introduced by macrolet. They only exist at compilation time, and macroexpand (when you call it directly) operates at run time. Your test only works because you defined `when` the same way clojure.core does. But, macrolet will solve your problem as long as you don't want to expand at run time.

Comment: @Hamza If you don't mind depending on some non-core libraries, you can also use the `macro` part of my `amalloy-utils` [package](https://github.com/amalloy/amalloy-utils/blob/master/src/amalloy/utils/macro.clj#L18), which includes `anon-macro` (to allow `macrolet` without naming it at all) and `macro-do` (for rewriting your "use N times" named `macrolet` into a "use once with lots of args" `anon-macro` form).

Answer (score 2):

Digging through contrib, found what I was looking for,

```
(use ' clojure.contrib.macro-utils)
(macrolet [(when [test & body]
             (list 'if test (cons 'do body)))]

          (macroexpand '(when true 4)))
```

```
(if true (do 4))
```